# Can a quantum computer break quantum cryptography?

Tags: quantum-algorithms, cryptography

I’m not sure if this makes sense, but I know that there is quantum and post-quantum encryption, and I’m curious whether quantum computing can break a quantum encryption.

Comment: perhaps you mean ECC type cryptography? See https://security.stackexchange.com/a/261196/8618

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is a good question that highlights the unfortunately broad use of the term "quantum cryptography".  Either way, the TL/DR of it is that, although quantum computers break many currently used classical public key distribution protocols, we also have:

- Provably, **no**, quantum computers will *not* be able to break encryption with keys exchanged with various [quantum key distribution (QKD) protocols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_key_distribution); and
- Conjecturally, **no**, quantum computers should *not* be able to break public-key encryption based on various [post-quantum cryptography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post-quantum_cryptography) schemes.

---

In more detail, in many of the quantum key distribution schemes, such as the [BB84](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BB84) protocol and the [E91](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_key_distribution#E91_protocol:_Artur_Ekert_.281991.29) protocol, qubits are exchanged between parties that wish to communicate.  These protocols are based on the [no-cloning theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No-cloning_theorem), and are *information-theoretically* secure.  This implies that no amount of computational power would be sufficient to crack ciphers based on these protocols.  However, practical implementations of such schemes might indeed have other serious vulnerabilities - the machine that sent photons in the very first implementation of BB84 made different sounds, depending on whether it was sending qubits in the $\mid\leftrightarrow\rangle,\mid\updownarrow\rangle$ basis or the $\mid\circlearrowleft\rangle,\mid\circlearrowright\rangle$ basis!

Compare the information-theoretical security of QKD protocols to the many protocols currently used for secure [public-key communication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography), such as RSA and Diffie-Hellman, along with elliptic-curve based schemes.  For example, these cryptographic schemes were thought to be *computationally* secure, in the sense that the resources used to crack these schemes were thought to grow exponentially with key sizes.  Of course, the big break-through of Shor is that no, these schemes are *not* secure in the presence of powerful-enough quantum computers.

Accordingly, partly because we do not yet have a "quantum internet" powerful enough to securely implement QKD protocols to trade qubits around the world, and we only have the "classical internet", the race is on to find public-key cryptosystems that don't involve trading qubits between Alice and Bob but are nonetheless *conjectured* to be computationally secure even in a world of quantum computers.  This is the meaning of "post" in post-quantum cryptography.  These are classical protocols that are conjectured to be computationally secure against even a quantum computer.

---

Post-quantum cryptography began as a field, after the development of both quantum key distribution schemes and Shor's algorithm. The last line of Jennifer and Peter Shor's lovely [limerick](https://klein.mit.edu/%7Eshor/notapoet.html) on the cat-and-mouse games of using a quantum computer to read e-mails could probably also be changed to "Till we've crypto that's -post- quantum, and daunt 'em." But that might not scan as nicely.